# дополнить трехмерный массив numpy нулями

Tags: python, numpy

у меня есть файл npy, там на самом деле хранится картинка.
Мне нужно дозаполнить его нулями.

Допустим было [30,40,200],[45,42,200], а нужно [700,500, 200].

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать?

я пробовала так:

```
import numpy as np

abc1=np.ones((2,7,8))
abc= np.arange(12).reshape(2, 2, 3)
print(abc)
#print(np.pad(abc[0,0,:],(2,3),"constant"))
for i in range(2):
    abc1[i,:,:]=np.pad(abc[i,:,:],(2,3),"constant")
print(abc1.shape)
print('\n')
print(abc1)
```

Comment: По какой логике это получилось?`было [30,40,200],[45,42,200] а нужно [700,500, 200]`

Comment: ну просто добавляется необходимое количество нулей до 700 и 500

Comment: только как бы я наверное не совсем поняла. изображение состоит из слоев. их 200. и вот я сохраняла их в массив когда загружала. получилось, что массив имел размерность [ширина, высота, 200]

Comment: imarray=np.zeros((A,B,H))
    for i in range(H-1):
        im=Imag.open(path+'\\'+jIm[i*2])
        imarray[:,:,i]= np.array(im)

Comment: дальше он обрезался и получалась размерность что то типа  [A-alpha,B-beta,H]. И таких массивов много. Они разные в первых двух измерениях. Я их просто обрезала , чтобы выделить область интереса. Теперь хочу дополнить по размерам макисмального из них и сделать их всех одинакового размера по ширине и высоте.

Comment: Oopss, просто я только начала писать на питон. и вот наткнулась на статью, где показано, что первое число в размерности это и есть глубина. я запуталась((((

Comment: По идее `np.pad` должен помочь, только разберитесь с параметрами.

Comment: Все-таки интересно, как это нужно дополнить 30 нулями, чтобы получилось 700?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

orig_size, target_size, fill_value = (30, 40, 200), (700, 500, 200), 0
a = np.ones(orig_size)
b = np.pad(a, [(0, ts - os) for ts, os in zip(target_size, orig_size)], mode='constant', constant_values=fill_value)
print(f'{a.shape} >> {b.shape}')
```

```
(30, 40, 200) >> (700, 500, 200)
```